# как с локалки на хостинг загрузить magento

Tags: magento, хостинг

Неделю потрудился над magento,настало время с локалки залить на хостинг, по гуглил ответа не нашел. Обычным методом тут замучаешься(я так подумал), может есть какие то правила, легкие способы?

P.S. На хостинге(Beget) есть возможность установить Magento, подумал есть ли возможность (инструменты, правила) если на хостинг отдельно установить и синхронизировать с локалкой?

Comment: ха-ха, в рукоде у меня ноль просмотров))))

Answer (score 2):

Делаем бэкап базы и файлов:

> tar -xvzf name.tar.gz
>
> mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD DATABASE | gzip >
>   /path/to/outputfile.sql.gz

Заливаем на лайв и распаковываем:

> tar -cvzf name.tgz ./ --exclude=var
>
> gunzip < /path/to/outputfile.sql.gz | mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD
>   DATABASE
>
> setfacl -Rm u:www-data:rwx -dRm u:www-data:rwx ./

Не забываем поменять в **core_config_data** `web/unsecure/base_url` на урл локального хоста

Answer (score 1):

Любым менеджером БД (mySQL) или какая у вас.
+ FTP
Сам на хостинге бегет, но ни когда, не ставлю ни чего чужого.

Comment: Аха, сейчас я делаю в ручную, mysql отдельно загрузил, файлы через FTP отдельно загрузил, щас попробую в файле local.xml изменить данные и в БД в таблице core_config_data базовый юрл изменить, посмотрим че получится

Comment: О, класс, все нормально работает

Answer (score 0):

А что особенного по сравнению с другими cms? Делаешь бэкап базы mysql на локальном хосте. Переносишь на хостинг файлы cms, файл бэкапа БД с локального хоста. Импортируешь файл БД в БД на хостинге, настраиваешь права на файлы. Наверное самое муторное настроить авторизацию для для доступа к БД на хостинге. Прописываешь в файле конфигурации CMS на хостинге пользователя , пароль от БД на хостинге. Вроде бы все.